# C# How do I copy tables and stored procedures to an empty mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I have created a database in C#, and the mdf is in a specified location also attached to the same server (it is a backup database).

Now I want to know how to copy all the tables together with its data, definitions, and stored procedures from one table to the newly created one. Basically, they would be the same database with a different name and will be stored in a different location. I don't intend  to use .bak by the way if someone suggests it.

Will I be able to do this in a query? or better yet, in C#? Or maybe I'm doing this wrong. Any suggestions will be welcome with open arms.

Comment: But do you need to keep the backup loaded? Why don't you simply take the backup file and store it in a safe location ready to be restored when needed?

Comment: @Steve I will be detaching it in C# afterwards because after the process, the media that the mdf is stored to will be ejected from the machine. I didn't want to create a bak file  just to copy the tables unless there is no other option.

Comment: I haven't tried this with SQL Server but tools like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php) allow you to export the entire database as a plaintext .sql file which you can later "replay". To rename the DB you can manually (or programmatically) edit the .sql file.

Answer (score 3):

#### Summary

With Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) you can right click on your database, select `tasks`, then `generate scripts`.  This will bring up a wizard.  In the `Choose Objects` step, you can select a radio button that will allow you to select your database tables individually.  The next step `Set Scripting Options` will give you the ability to create a script in a single file, a file per object (table, sproc, etc).  At this point you can click next through the rest of the wizard or review the steps.

If you use a script file, this can be used to recreate your database.  Just modify the `USE [YourDbNameHere]`.

#### Reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245282.aspx